# SFDX source pull field dependencies

Tags: relationships, salesforcedx, field-dependencies

I have two dependent picklists on an object created in a scratch org which are successfully retrieved with a force:source:pull.

The field dependency between them, however, is not included in the pull.

Is there anything specific that needs to be done for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 18 months later, and had cause to do this again today.  The solution to this is to make a change to the actual object itself, no matter how small.

The dependencies will then pull from the scratch org.

Comment: this is really unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

You can use sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:[object name].[custom field name] to retrieve the dependencies.